# How to set css property dynamically for each row using Database (using inline css) in VUE - Vue good table

Tags: database, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-good-table

Can someone help me with the custom style for each row? I need to set the background color of each row dynamically. I read the complete document with an example but did not found any solution for this. I found that a custom class is available.

```
        <vue-good-table
        :columns="columns"
        :rows="rows"
        styleClass="vgt-table">
        </vue-good-table>
```

But I need a custom style instead of a class like a background color that will be served from DB in the SST table.
Thanks

Comment: I haven't done what you are trying to do, but did a search out of curiosity, and found CSS variables.  If not familiar, I would search 'css variables javascript'.  I haven't used SASS or LESS either, but possibly they could help, especially if you are using Vue CLI with Webpack.

Comment: It could be done if you wanted to conditionally apply a class, but not a single style property.  Is there a reason you don't want to use a class?

Comment: @Dan I want to fetch background property from the database for each row, is it possible to perform this with a class?

Comment: Yes it's possible with a class.  Make a class for each color you will use and then pass that classname from the database.  If that's a solution that would be acceptable, I can show you how.